# Update HTML table to have header JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv

I've read a CSV file into a HTML table with the result looking like this:

```
<div id="myTable" style="-ms-overflow-x: auto;">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="rownum-0">
                <td>Make</td>
                <td>Model</td>
                <td>Engine</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rownum-1">
                <td>Ford</td>
                <td>Escort</td>
                <td>Diesel</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

But I need the first row to be read in as headers.

I'm looking to either change the table so that the row where class="rownum-0" becomes a header or change the code which reads in the CSV file to read the first row as a header.

The code which I have used to read in the CSV is as below:

```
function table_load(){ 
    var urls = "http://mysite/Data/CarData.csv"
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urls,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#myTable').append(arrayToTable(Papa.parse(data).data));
            }
    }); 
}
function arrayToTable(tableData) {
    var myTable = $('<table></table>');
    $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
        var row = $('<tr class="rownum-' + [i] +'"></tr>');
        $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
            row.append($('<td>'+cellData+'</td>'));
        });
        myTable.append(row);
    });
    return myTable;
}
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for the past week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the first row where you generate the `<td></td>`, here is the simple things.

```
function arrayToTable(tableData) {
var myTable = $('<table></table>');
$(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
    var row = $('<tr class="rownum-' + [i] +'"></tr>');
    $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
       // change here
       // add conditional statement here. 
       var cell = '<td>'+cellData+'</td>';
       if (i === 0) {
         cell = '<th>'+cellData+'</th>';
       }
        row.append($(cell));
    });
    myTable.append(row);
});
 return myTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use below code, just check first data and insert it into `<th>` otherwise into `<tr>`.

```
function arrayToTable(tableData) {
    var myTable = $('<table></table>');
    $(tableData).each(function (i, rowData) {
        row = $('<tr class="rownum-' + i +'"></tr>');
        if(i == 0) {            
            $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
                row.append($('<th>'+cellData+'</th>'));
            });
        } else {                 
            $(rowData).each(function (j, cellData) {
                row.append($('<td>'+cellData+'</td>'));
            });
        }
        myTable.append(row);
    });
    return myTable;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it created the headers as expected but misaligned the body